# Accessing the first item of list values that occur irregularly in a Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a pandas dataframe and in one of the columns a list value appears in some of the values. I need to be able to extract the first item of the list, if it's a list, and if it's not a list then the value will be unchanged. I am struggling to achieve it using the lambda function:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Fruits':['Apple',['Banana',6],'Kiwi','Cheese']})

df1['Fruits'] = df1['Fruits'].apply(lambda(x): x[0] if (type(x) == 'list') else x)
```

If I use the above the column remains unchanged. I am guessing this must be a problem with the conditional statement within the lambda function....

I would also be interested if there is a better way of achieving this within Pandas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove `''` from `'list'` to `list`:

```
df1['Fruits'] = df1['Fruits'].apply(lambda  x : x[0] if type(x) == list else x)
print (df1)
   Fruits
0   Apple
1  Banana
2    Kiwi
3  Cheese
```

Similar solution is use `isinstance`:

```
df1['Fruits'] = df1['Fruits'].apply(lambda x: x[0] if isinstance(x, list) else x)
print (df1)
   Fruits
0   Apple
1  Banana
2    Kiwi
3  Cheese
```

Or is possible use `list comprehension`:

```
df1['Fruits'] = [x[0] if type(x) == list else x for x in df1['Fruits']]
print (df1)
   Fruits
0   Apple
1  Banana
2    Kiwi
3  Cheese
```

Comment: Nice solutions but a very stupid mistake from me. I was certain that previously I had checked for a variable type using quotation marks so didn't even think to change this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad can help, I think some `(` missing problem first.